# argparser not recognizing values from gradle exec task

Tags: python, gradle, build.gradle, argparse

I am trying to run a python script in a gradle task but when I pass in the arguments they are get the value of None.

Here is the gradle task:

```
def foo= tasks.register('foo', Exec) {
group 'Foo'
commandLine 'python3'
args 'foo.py', 
     '--file', "/path/in",
     '--outputDir',"/path/out"
}
```

Here is the python script that it is calling:

```
import argparse
from argparse import Namespace

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--file')
parser.add_argument('--outputDir')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Output:

```
Namespace(imageFile=None, outputDir=None)
```

Desired Output:

```
Namespace(imageFile="/path/in", outputDir="/path/out")
```

Comment: check `sys.argv` to see what the parser has to work with.  I don't think it's getting any values.

Comment: If it got values that it didn't recognize, it would have raised an error.

Comment: seems to work ok in gradle 7.2 ; which version are you running